# How to reach the page setup dialog box on post 5.0.2 releases?

Tags: libreoffice

LibreOffice does not allow page setup, ie the paper size and orientation cannot be set. This problem occurs in all of the LibreOffice programs: Writer, Calc, Impress, Draw, Math and Base.

I've tried this both with the 5.0.2 release available in the software archives, and the 5.0.3-rc2 candidate from the launchpad/libreoffice ppa.

Does anyone have a work-around or patch for this?

Comment: Where, in Writer, Calc, ...?

Comment: All of them.  I wasn't specific in the question, because it crosses lines in the packages.  I will update the question...

Comment: The is no menu entry Format -> Page? Works here with Build ID: 1:5.0.3~rc2-0ubuntu1

Comment: For me, in writer the menu options are file->printer settings, then click on the button 'options' to change the paper size or page layout.  Do you have another method for getting to that, or is my installation funky somehow?

Comment: I can go to the menu format->page and accomplish the task I have been looking to do (change to landscape).  Somehow I overlooked that when I found the entries under file->print do not work.  Panicked, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the menu entry <kbd>Format</kbd> > <kbd>Page</kbd> in Writer, Calc, Impress, Draw, Math or Base.

Select the tab <kbd>Page</kbd>.

Here you will find everything that makes you happy for the rest of the day ... ! **;)**

Answer (score 2):

In LibreOffice Writer, you can format the page using "Format" menu, select "Page..." and the options are in there.

I am using Ubutntu Studio 15.10 with L.O. 5.0.2.2.

Comment: I accepted A.B.'s answer, although later than your answer, simply because he had been conversing with me on the problem through the commend system for a while.